# spark Exception in thread "main" java

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

when i use `spark-shell` i got this after installing pyspark by pip

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/spark/launcher/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

same as using `pyspark` command,and spark-version is 1.6.0

Comment: how did you install spark ?

Comment: The problem is that you compiled with/for Java 8, but you are running Spark on Java 7 or older. The best way to resolve this is to install Java 8 on all your nodes, including the driver.